# jquery ui error for ui.draggable("destroy")

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to remove the drag property of a `<div>` when I drop it on a container. But I get an error `"Property 'draggable' of object #<Object> is not a function"`, for my code below.

```
$( "#fighter1" ).draggable(); //fighter1 is the id of draggable object
$( "#fighter2" ).draggable();
$( "#fighter3" ).draggable();
$( "#fighter4" ).draggable();
$( "#fighter5" ).draggable();
$( "#fighter6" ).draggable();
$( "#dest" ).droppable({      //dest is the id of droppable object
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.draggable("destroy"); //I get error here.
   }
});
```

I use the jquery ui version 1.8.12

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you might want to consider using a class for the draggables when you have so many. Ex: `$( ".draggable" ).draggable();`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that 'ui' is a simple old javascript object rather than a jQuery object.
Try (REVISED):
`$(ui.draggable).draggable("destroy");`

Comment: but when i try to get the id of the object it gives me null.

Comment: Ah, my jquery-ui is rusty it seems, according to the jquery-ui demos:  
"  $(this) represents the droppable the draggable is dropped on. ui.draggable represents the draggable. " See revision.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for calling [methods of draggable widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method) is:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "method" );
```

You should pass the method name as a `string` to the `draggable()` method.

Inside the drop event callback, `ui.draggable` is just a reference to the jQuery object corresponding to the draggable element (the `$( ".selector" )` part of syntax).

You should actually invoke `draggable()` on it and pass the method name:

```
ui.draggable.draggable("destroy");
----^-------        ------^------
selector                method name
       --------^--------
   this guy executes the method
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem using setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function(a){a.draggable("destroy");},100,ui.draggable);
```