# jQuery droppable object executes destroy() but throws an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, destroy

When I run this

```
$('#tgsBox1').droppable({
    accept: "#tgsSquirrel",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        ui.draggable.animate({
            left: $(this).position().left + 25,
            top: $(this).position().top + 131
        }).destroy();
    }
});
```

The draggable element is actually destroyed (is not draggable anymore) but it gives an error:

```
TypeError: ui.draggable.animate(...).destroy is not a function
ui.draggable.animate({
```

Looks similar to the old thread: [jquery ui error for ui.draggable("destroy")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024990/jquery-ui-error-for-ui-draggabledestroy), but the assumed solution (updating the jQuery-ui) doesn't sort that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for calling methods in jQuery ui dragglable widget is:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "method" );
```

for [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy): `$( ".selector" ).draggable( "destroy" );`

Try calling the method as follows:

```
$('#tgsBox1').droppable({
  accept: "#tgsSquirrel",
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    ui.draggable.animate({
        left: $(this).position().left + 25,
        top: $(this).position().top + 131
    }).draggable("destroy");
  }
});
```

The reason why it isn't draggable anymore is probably because script execution stopped due to the error.

You might want to destroy the draggable after animation is completed as well:

```
$('#tgsBox1').droppable({
  accept: "#tgsSquirrel",
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    ui.draggable.animate({
        left: $(this).position().left + 25,
        top: $(this).position().top + 131
    },function(){
       ui.draggable.draggable("destroy");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Great. Thank you very much (I'd like to vote up your answer but my reputation is yet too low). What I don't understand is: why do I need to call the "destroy" method for a draggable object of the draggable object? In other words: What is the difference between the two draggable objects in `ui.draggable.draggable`?

Comment: @Robbit does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27385683/2333214) this help..? You can't call widget functions directly like `.destroy()`, you have to pass the name of the method as a string to the `draggable()` factory function. The factory will compare the string and call corresponnding method in it. The actual name of the method inside facory might be something else...